# Stuck on "Update pending" when install an extension via web setup wizard, Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2

I was stuck while installing an extension pack, here is my screen:
I used: windows 10, PHP 7.2.0 ( xampp ), Magento 2.3.2

[image: Admin page]

If you need any additional information I will provide.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show me some more details, because I don't get any error here.

Comment: I just got stuck like this, I checked the log and there were no errors

Comment: you can use command for update and install, Extension